# Inserting new row into access

Tags: c#, ado.net, ms-access-2007

Maybe I'm doing it wrong, but I'm trying to use ado.net to insert a new row into a table. It's telling me the syntax is wrong, though.

```
customers = new DataTable("Customers");
cmd = "SELECT * FROM Customers";
con = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd, strconn);
con.FillSchema(customers, SchemaType.Source);
con.Fill(customers);
DataRow cur;
cur = customers.NewRow();
cur["Company"] = textBoxCompany.Text;
cur["First Name"] = textBoxFirstName.Text;
cur["Last Name"] = textBoxLastName.Text;
cur["E-mail Address"] = textBoxEmail.Text;
cur["Job Title"] = textBoxTitle.Text;
cur["Business Phone"] = textBoxPhone.Text;
customers.Rows.Add(cur);
OleDbCommandBuilder cb = new OleDbCommandBuilder(con);
con.InsertCommand = cb.GetInsertCommand();           
con.InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("Company",cur["Company"]);
con.InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("Last Name",cur["Last Name"]);
con.InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("First Name", cur["First Name"]);
con.InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("E-Mail Address",cur["E-mail Address"]);
con.InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("Job Title",cur["Job Title"]);
con.InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("Business Phone",cur["Business Phone"]);
con.Update(customers);
```

"Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement."

Stack trace:

```
at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.UpdatedRowStatusErrors(RowUpdatedEventArgs rowUpdatedEvent, BatchCommandInfo[] batchCommands, Int32 commandCount)
at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.UpdatedRowStatus(RowUpdatedEventArgs rowUpdatedEvent, BatchCommandInfo[] batchCommands, Int32 commandCount)
at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Update(DataRow[] dataRows, DataTableMapping tableMapping)
at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.UpdateFromDataTable(DataTable dataTable, DataTableMapping tableMapping)
at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Update(DataTable dataTable)
at Project2.Form1.button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in Form1.cs:line 54
```

Comment: What is the exact error?

Comment: Are your field names actually called, e.g., `First Name`, `E-mail Address` in the database with spaces and `-`?  It looks like `OleDbCommandBuilder` might not support columns with spaces: http://www.vbdotnetforums.com/database-general-discussion/19146-oledbcommandbuilder-columns-w-spaces.html

Comment: @mellamokb: I'm fairly certain. I used the Northwind DB for this.
http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/templates/desktop-northwind-2007-sample-database-TC001228997.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tf579hcz.aspx) on command generation

> Automatic command generation logic fails if column names or table
>   names contain any special characters, such as spaces, periods,
>   quotation marks, or other nonalphanumeric characters, even if
>   delimited by brackets. Fully qualified table names in the form of
>   catalog.schema.table are supported.

Since your column names have spaces, the query will not work.  You will have to manually create the insert statement, which is fairly simple.  Just put brackets around all of the column names, and use parameters for the values that don't have spaces or special characters.

```
INSERT INTO [TableName] ([Column1], [Column2], ...)
VALUES (@Column1, @Column2, ...)
```

And you would use these parameter names as well in your parameter creation:

```
con.InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@column1", cur["..."]);
```

Comment: Can he do that with the code he's already got, e.g., `con.InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("[Last Name]",cur["Last Name"])`?

Comment: @Loadmaster: I don't believe you use column names with `AddWithValue`, but rather parameter names.  And you can't call a parameter `[Last Name]` with the spaces.